# Environment variables from Shibboleth not being passed when using ProxyPass

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, vhosts, shibboleth

I'm using Shibboleth along w/ Apache (w/ mod_proxy) and I've noticed that environment variables such as `REMOTE_USER` are not making it all the way to my application.

I have a virtual host that looks something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com

  <Location /Shibboleth.sso>
    ProxyPass !
  </Location>

  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9292/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9292/

  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Requests are proxy passed to a Ruby on Rails application running w/ the Puma webserver but when I inspect `request.ENV` I do not see my shibboleth attributes. Does anyone have any experience w/ something like this?

Comment: Did you specify you want to use AuthType shibboleth? If you think that the virtualhost is right, verify that you set the attribute to be extracted for saml message from IdP (in your sp see attribute-map.xml, by default)

Comment: ..... Then for setting REMOTE_USER you can set a priority list of these attributes, see the examples here https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPApplication#Examples

Answer (score 0):

Set `ShibUseHeaders` in your Apache config:

```
  <Location />
    AuthType shibboleth
    ShibRequireSession On
    ShibUseHeaders On
    Require valid-user
  </Location>
```

Then you should get the attributes as "HTTP_VARNAME" and use them out of request.ENV